# Foreach em uma ActionResult de detalhes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma entidade *Registro* que possui um *Professor*, o *Professor* tem uma lista de *Registro*. Como posso criar um **foreach** na View de detalhes do *Registro* pra listar do nome do *Professor* que pertence ao registro em questão ?

Controller registro:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        RegistroCompleto registroCompleto = db.RegistrosCompletos.Find(id);
        if (registroCompleto == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(registroCompleto);
}
```

View de detalhes do registro:

```
@model Meu.Projeto.Registro

<div>

    <dl class="dl-horizontal">

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Professor.Nome)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Professor.Nome)
        </dd>


    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.IdRegistroCompleto }) 
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Classe Registro:

```
public class Registro : RepositorioBase<Registro>
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Número do registro")]
    public int IdRegistroCompleto { get; set; }

    public Professor Professor { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data de cadastro")]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public int IdProfessor { get; set; }
 }
```

Classe professor:

```
public class Professor : RepositorioBase<Professor>, IProfessor
{
     [Key]
     public int IdProfessor { get; set; } 

     public List<RegistroCompleto> RegistrosCompletos { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Coloque as classes envolvidas?

Comment: Acebei de alterar o código

Comment: `RegistroCompleto` faltou essa ???

Comment: Tava errado o nome da classe, agora esta certa

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente acredito que sua classe `RegistroCompleto` deva conter uma `ICollection` de detalhes. Sendo assim, basta você carregar os detalhes na sua action da seguinte e forma:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            RegistroCompleto registroCompleto = db.RegistrosCompletos.Include(a=>a.Detalhes).FirstOrDefault(a=>a.Id == id);
            if (registroCompleto == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(registroCompleto);
        }
```

Já na View é só adicionar os `foreach` dos detalhes.

```
@model Meu.Projeto.RegistroCompleto

    <div>

        <dl class="dl-horizontal">

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Professor.Nome)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Professor.Nome)
            </dd>


        </dl>
    </div>
@foreach(var detalhe in Model.Detalhes)
{
    <span>@detalhe.Propriedade</span>
}
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.IdRegistroCompleto }) 
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
```

Comment: Na verdade Detalhes não é uma classe, só queria mostrar o nome do professor que pertence ao registro na View do registro